# How to return multiple records from a result set?

Tags: perl, teradata, dbi

I am using perl dbi and getting the sql results however it's coming as an array. The problem is , it only returns 1 array element. I tried to push to get the next element but there is nothing. I am sure (with other tool) I can see there are more then one values. It is (from other tool) I get multiple ddls. With my query I am only getting one of them.  Here is my query:

```
my $rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref
                  ("show SELECT * FROM TABLE
                   INNER JOIN TABLE1 
                   ON bla bla ;");

my $len = @$rows;
print  $len;
foreach $h (@$rows) {
    $st = $h->[0];
    $st =~ s/(\d),(\d)/\1|\2/g;
    @lines = split/,/,$st;
    foreach $x (@lines) {
        print FH $x . "\n";
    }
}
```

My question is how do I shift the same array and get next result set from same row?  Thanks!

The result of the above code is below:

### PRIMARY INDEX ( ProcID ,CollectTimeStamp );ONE)NICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC,,OT    NULL,C,

I don't think it brings back the entire content, somehow it is not complete

Comment: Where is `@lines` coming from? What database driver do you use? How do you populate `$rows`?

Comment: Sorry I missed some code. I am splitting it: @lines = split/,/,$st;   Since the first result is coming from all in one line and I am breaking part. I am using Teradata ODBC driver, 'dbi:ODBC. I am populating with selectall_arrayref($sql) and I have also tried: fetch_all_array.  Thanks!

Comment: Please, update the code in the question accordingly.

Comment: I've edited your code to add some indentation (and a little bit of whitespace). You're welcome, but please do it yourself in the future. Good indentation is an important tool to help people (including you!) understand your code. If you're asking a large group of strangers to read and understand your code, it's only polite to make that as easy as possible for them.

Comment: You probably want `for my $st ( @$h ) { ... } ` but it's very hard to tell with such a tiny sample of code and no data.

Comment: I have updated the code again .Please let me know what should I change.

Comment: **`INNIER`** join?

Comment: @PerlDuck, the SQL can be anything but with a show prefix in Teradata should display all the object name and it's definition (DDL) one after another. Say on this Inner join if there are 2 tables (table and table1) the result you expect two ddls for the above tables. Hope that explains and thanks!

Comment: Before doing fancy things with your results (like `s///` and `split`) I'd make sure that the (unprocessed!) result actually contains what you expect it to. Add `use Data::Dumper;` somewhere at the top and `print Data::Dumper::Dumper( $rows );` right after your `my $rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(…)`. /// I'm pretty sure the SQL after `show` can _not_ be anything. I presume it must be valid SQL at least.

Comment: @PerlDuck, did that and somehow it is printing 1 ddl still. Here it looks like: $VAR1 = [
          [
      DDL1,
          ]
        ];   That makes me wonder if Selectall_arrayref () is not the right method to use? Any thoughts? thanks

Comment: Then perhaps the DB driver for Teradata doesn't properly support the `show` statement. I cannot tell; I never heard of Teradata before.

Comment: @PerlDuck The odbc driver does support it as I am able to use other third party tool and getting proper results. I think its is the selectall_array method has the issue of not returning all contents. Are there anything else I can try? Also beside DBI library are there any other way to do this? thanks

Comment: The [docs say](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.637/DBI.pm#selectall_arrayref) `selectall_arrayref` is just a shortcut for `prepare`, `execute` and `fetchall_arrayref`. You can try, but I have doubts.

Comment: @PerlDuck, I tried that fetchall_arrayref too but same thing. I am definitely missing something.....

Comment: Any other suggestions? Appreciate any help

Comment: @AftabKhan: I've fixed the indentation in your code for a second time. Why did you break the work I had previously done? I also fixed a typo (`INNER` vs `INNIER`). Please don't just type code into your question - cut and paste your **actual** code to avoid wasting our time.

Comment: I always refer to this post http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=284436 when dealing with DBI.

Answer (score 0):

[This probably counts as "not an answer", but I'm trying to extract more useful information from the OP, and it's far easier to show him the code I want him to run in an answer]

We still really have no idea what you are trying to do here. And, to be honest, I'm not convinced that you do either :-)

Let's have a look at the raw data - without any of the processing that you're adding. Please try running the following code and then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47891005/edit) to add the output (if it returns a number of rows, you only need to include a couple).

```
my $rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref
                  ("show SELECT * FROM TABLE
                   INNER JOIN TABLE1 
                   ON bla bla ;");

foreach my $row (@$rows) {
  print join(' / ', @$row), "\n";
}
```

Then, please tell us (using those rows as an example) what output you want.

Comment: I already asked something similar [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891005/how-to-return-multiple-records-from-a-result-set#comment82753715_47891005). They say it prints just one record (`scalar(@$rows) == 1`).

Comment: Also to add my query result of that "Show" command should be two DDLs that is two create table statement with all the columns indexes etc. Thanks!

Comment: @AftabKhan: Why have you ignored my request?

Comment: @DaveCross, I am sorry I did not see your post. It was in intentional. Next time I will follow the indenting you recommended only reason I was not posting all the query is to avoid any proprietary issue since some of the code could be exposed and violate some guidelines of the company. Any way back to the point, I think SELECTALL_ARRAYREF is not handling my request properly. Are there anything else I can try? thanks

Comment: @AftabKhan: You did not see my post, but you replied to it. That seems... unlikely :-) It also seems unlikely that `selectall_arrayref()` doesn't work for your question when it works for every other query in the universe, ever! There are, of course, many other DBI methods that you can use for fetching the results of a query, but I suspect they will all be broken in exactly the same way. If you don't want to share the output of your query with us, then I'm afraid I can't be any more help to you.

Comment: @DaveCross sorry if I have felt you confused or made me confused but I am lost and did not get it to work.  I did edit my question and put the output there. Not sure what else do I need to do.  If you give me your email may be I can talk to you direct

Comment: @AftabKhan: You included the output of your code. What I asked for was the output of my code - along with an example of what you want the output to be. I'd be happy to help you privately over email, but private help isn't free.

Comment: @DaveCross, Sorry for the delay as I was in vacation. However I did run as you suggested and the results are the same. See below:                   --------------------------------------------
                             --------------------------------------------
                             PRIMARY INDEX ( UserId );RACTER                                       SET                              LATIN                                UPPERCASE NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL),